# Get hovered word from hover() in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make an auto translate from the word that I mouse over on it. I use

```
$('p').hover(function () {
  var hoveredWord = $(this).text();
  translate(hoveredWord, 'en'); // function to translate a word to English Language
});
```

It will return the whole text within the paragraph, however, I just want a word that I hover not the whole text. Is there any function in Jquery I can use to archive this? thanks.

Comment: This may be a bit overkill but you could put each word in the `p` in it's own span, like: `<p><spa>The</span> <span>quick</span> <span>fox</span> etc..</p>`. Then you can add the `hover` to each to `span`.

Comment: in this case you have to wrap your each word inside the span/label tag. so you will be able to perform event on that

Comment: `hover` is  combination of `mouseover` and `mouseout` event in `Jquery` so it wiil return all the paragraph if you mouseover a paragraph

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do in a different way. I would wrap all the text content using `<span>`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('p').html(function () {
    var cont = [];
    return "<span>" + $(this).text().split(" ").join("</span> <span>") + "</span>";
  }).on("mouseover", "span", function() {
    var hoveredWord = $(this).text();
    console.log(hoveredWord);
    // translate(hoveredWord, 'en'); // function to translate a word to English Language
  });
});
```

```css
span:hover {background: #ccf;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello, World! How are you?</p>
```

And I won't use the `hover` function. It is unreliable and deprecated.