# how to use AJAX in JSF 2.0 to get the word the mouse is over?

Tags: ajax, jsf, mouseover

is there a way to get the word the mouse is over on by using AJAX on JSF 2.0 (which even works on outputText component)?

My goal is to store that word on a bean variable (let's say #{bean.selectedWord}) to use for further operations.

Up to now I'm only able to get the entire value of the  inputText element... I was wondering if I had to use jQuery too.

**page.xhtml**

```
     <h:inputText id = "myIinput" value="this is a test">
        <f:ajax event="mouseover" render="myOutput" execute="myInput"
                listener="#{bean.ajaxFunction}"/>
     </h:inputText>
     <h:outputText id ="myOutput" value="#{bean.selectedWord}" />
```

**bean.java**

```
String selectedWord;

  public void ajaxFunction(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    UIComponent uic = event.getComponent();
    String output = (String) uic.getAttributes().get("value");
    myOutput = output ;
  }

  public String getSelectedWord(){
    return selectedWord
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain JSF nor any of the component suites I know of has a component for this. So effectively you need to break down your problem in two:

- client side in javascript (with or without the help of a js framework like jquery) find the word a client hovers over. This is adressed in e.g.

  - [How to get a word under cursor using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444430/how-to-get-a-word-under-cursor-using-javascript#2444462)
  - [Get hovered word from hover() in Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45304367/get-hovered-word-from-hover-in-jquery)
- send a javascript value to the server via some ajax call, which is addressed in

  - [How to invoke a JSF managed bean on a HTML DOM event using native JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588327/how-to-invoke-a-jsf-managed-bean-on-a-html-dom-event-using-native-javascript)

Combine the two and you have your solution. But don't forget to add a delay  in the hover so not every qucik hover isemd, just when the user pauses.